# Python hickle SerializedWarning when using dataclass

Tags: python, hickle

I have a dataclass

```
@dataclass
class ImageFile:
    path: str
    folder: str
```

when trying to save this list using hickle

```
hkl.dump(ImageList)
```

it leads to this warning

```
\lib\site-packages\hickle\lookup.py:1491: SerializedWarning: 'ImageFile' type not understood, data is serialized:
```

should I be worried?

Answer (score 0):

A [`SerializedWarning`](https://github.com/telegraphic/hickle/blob/v5.0.2/hickle/lookup.py#L159) in `hickle` means that no custom loader is defined for `ImageFile`, so instances of it are going to be serialized as binary `pickle` strings (instead  of using a portable HDF5 data representation).

This usually isn't a problem, as long as you're ok with the objects being serialized with `pickle`. Such objects can be reloaded into Python trivially, but can't be easily loaded from into other programming languages or environments.

If you don't want `ImageFile` instances to be serialized with `pickle`, you can define a custom loader. See [Dumping custom objects](https://github.com/telegraphic/hickle#dumping-custom-objects).